# Pandoc citations without appending the references bibliography

Tags: pandoc, bibliography, citations

Main Question:
**Is there a way to flag Pandoc to turn off appending the bibliography but still have it insert the correct inline citations?**

I am writing a Markdown / Knitr document that has a main file (`article.Rmd`) and several "child" files that are included in the main file using Knitr's "child=" chunk option.

The child files are basically sections of the main article file, just separated for easier editing and management. Throughout these child section files, I use the [citations](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#citations) in the Markdown text (e.g. "@author_title_1999") to cite various papers. The main file and each child file has a YAML header that provides the BibTex file location, e.g.:

```
---
bibliography: mybibfile.bib  
...
```

(Including this YAML entry more than once is not a problem; see the [readme on metadata-blocks](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#metadata-blocks).)

When I compile the entire document using Knitr, a big Markdown document is created. I then use Pandoc with the `--filter pandoc-citeproc` option to manage the citations. Pandoc inserts nice citations and appends a list of the cited papers as references/bibliography. Cool.

As I write and edit the individual child sections, I use the same citation compiling which produces the correct inline citations, but unfortunately also appends the references at the end, even though it's just a section of the larger document. **I would like to compile these small child sections with inline citations, but without the bibliography at the end.**

Comment: It looks like the required feature has now been implemented in pandoc-citeproc. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is possible with the `suppress-bibliography` metadata field first introduced in [pandoc-citeproc 0.7](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/releases/tag/0.7) (released in May 2015). From the current [pandoc-citeproc man page](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/blob/master/man/pandoc-citeproc.1.md):

> pandoc-citeproc will look for the following metadata fields in the input:
>   ...
>   `suppress-bibliography` : If this has a true value, the bibliography will be left off. Otherwise a bibliography will be inserted into each Div element with id `refs`. If there is no such Div, one will be created at the end of the document.

(as a workaround, you can also quite easily create a custom CSL style that doesn't produce a bibliography, by deleting the `cs:bibliography` child element of the style. See http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#child-elements-of-cs-style.)

Comment: Thank Rintze. The suppress-bibliography option wasn't working for some reason, but the csl workaround you suggest did for me.